# Google Play developer console gives different values of sha1 digest of uploaded apk files

Tags: android, google-play

I have upgraded my application on play store three times, So there are three different apks, two of which are unpublished and other is Active.

Now, when I go to APK section of an Application Details page on Developer Console.

I see two APK under other APK section and one APK under Current APK Section.

Now when I click on one of those APK, it gives a popup giving some details, such as versionCode, versionName, Size etc. One of those details is APK file sha1 digest.

Now the strange thing is that, I am getting different values of APK file SHA1 digest for all the three APKs.

Is this expected behavior?
What does APK file sha1 digest mean?[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is exactly the expected behaviour.

The (SHA1) digest of a file is a unique number generated from the contents of the file. Each time you produce a new apk file it will be slightly different and it's digest will be different also. You can say that if the digest is the same then the files are identical.

If you want to check that a file is unchanged, say you download it from the store and you want to check that it was not modified since you uploaded it, you can do that if you have the digest of the original. That is what the play store is showing you here, the digest of the file that you uploaded.

You can generate the digest yourself with something like openssl, on OSX I can use this command:

openssl sha1 myapp.apk

And it will show me the digest. This should match the one in the play store. I often find this useful to make sure that I have uploaded the right apk file.